# Disable Browser Search and using my own search input on CTRL F

Tags: javascript, search

I am trying to disable the browser search functionlity and at the same time i want to focus my own custom search box in website.

here is code for the same.

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey || e.keyCode === 114) {
              document.getElementById("myInput").focus();
            }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

it disable the browser search feature and focus my custom search bar but it does not allow me to type anything in my custom search input.

Answer (score 2):

The `preventDefault()` should be used **only** if the relevant key is the `ctrl+f`:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey || e.keyCode === 114) {
    document.getElementById("myInput").focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="myInput" />
```

Otherwise you prevent any `keydown` that use is doing...

Answer (score 0):

keycode is now deprecated. Use this:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if ( (e.code == "0x0021" && e.key == "Control") || e.code == "0x003D") {
    document.getElementById("myInput").focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```
<input id="myInput" />
```